# Limite do número de respostas

Tags: suporte

Alguém consegue explicar porque quando tento colocar uma resposta, obtenho um erro dizendo que já ultrapassou o limite para esta conta[image]

Comment: Sim, isso [está explicado na Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans). Não deve ser o caso desta conta. Você criou uma nova conta só para poder postar alguma coisa?

Comment: Você pode postar um screenshot/printscreen do erro?

Comment: Imagem colocada

Comment: Bem, Alberto Ferreira, isso é algo que apenas os moderadores podem responder. CC @bigown.